# Can't boot into my Windows 7 64-bit Acer laptop

Tags: windows-7, acer-aspire

Boot normally -- it hangs on "Starting Windows" animation forever.

Boot safe mode -- it bluescreens.

Boot with a recovery CD (or try Repair Installation directly without a CD) -- it hangs on the green loading bar forever.

I dual-boot Ubuntu and can get into the Ubuntu partition fine so I don't think anything is necessarily wrong with the harddrive, but the Ubuntu partition is tiny and I rarely use it and can't access my Windows files anyway.

Is there anything I can try that'll help repair whatever happened? I just want to run a checkdisk utility or something similar that'll repair whatever got botched.

My laptop: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834215206

Comment: Any USB storage devices plugged in?  Have seen this casue a very long hang.  Almost 15 minutes with a USB DVD-RW once

Comment: No, nothing plugged in

Comment: For that note, nothing plugged in anywhere other than the power cord.

Comment: Test your memory modules....http://www.memtest.org/